# Java Search for word that contain double letter

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program to search for double character appearing side to side .
how ever my logic doesnt work. How can i fix this.

> ```
> Example word like
> 'apple'
> 'hello'
> ```
>
> expected output This +word+ will contain double letter

```
    System.out.println("Enter word: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = scanner.nextLine();
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word[i] == word[i + 1]) {
            System.out.println("word contain double letter");

        } else {
            System.out.println("normal word found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: Please provide the expected output and either the actual output or error message. We can't exactly help if we don't know what's wrong.

Comment: expected output will be 'word contain double letter' will be printed

Comment: Take your copy and pen with you and try to debug your code....by the way...why `i = 1` in your loop???

Comment: But what doesn't work about the code? Do you get a compiler error...? Is there an exception...?

Comment: You looped through a String without converting it to array.

Comment: I would expect an "ArrayOutOfBounds" exception ! No ?
Change the if condition to word[i] == word[i - 1] since you start with index = 1! I'm just telling what you can change in your code 

Also you might want to break out after sysout("... double letter")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Declare a boolean value
- Use `word.charAt(i)` for accessing characters in the string
- If found assign `found=true;`
- Finally check the    boolean and print appropriate message.

---

```
  System.out.println("Enter word: ");
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String word = scanner.nextLine();
                    int i = 0;
                    boolean found=false;
                    for (i = 0; i < word.length()-1; i++) {
                        if (word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i+1)) {
                            found=true;
                            break;
                        } 
                        }
                    if(found) {
                        System.out.println("word contain double letter");
                    }else
                        System.out.println("normal word found");
```

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there, you have 2 issues with your code:

1. In Java, to access characters you would need to use the `.charAt(int index)` method and not the way you have approach it (this would work in C# though). As a result, your code would not compile.
2. You have a slight mistake in your loop logic: The loop should start at `0` and end at `.length - 1`. Making those changes should work, as per the code below: Not doing this change will cause an `IndexOutofBoundsException`.

   ```
       System.out.println("Enter word: ");
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       String word = scanner.nextLine();
       int i = 0;

       for (i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++)
       {
           if (word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i + 1))
           {
               System.out.println("word contain double letter");

           } else
           {
               System.out.println("normal word found");
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: Your loop should be i = 1;

Comment: @Knx: If I were to do that, any string which would start with a double letter would be missed.

Comment: My bad. (Focusing on a single word to test. Hee hee) Why is that your code still shows the string "normal word found" even if it has shown the other string?

Comment: @Knx: The way I understood the question was that the OP's code was not printing `Word contain double letter`. For what you are after, you would need to look at the solution (and accepted answer) proposed by goowtham.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to loop over an array, you could use `toCharArray()` method to get a `String` as a `char[]` array:

```
char[] arr = word.toCharArray();
```

then loop over it. Also you would like to have a *flag* variable in order to keep the result if the word was normal or it has a double letter:

```
boolean hasDoubleLetter = false;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if(arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
        hasDoubleLetter = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

then depending on what was the result (`hasDoubleLetter`), print the corresponding message:

```
if (hasDoubleLetter) // true
    System.out.println(...);
else
    System.out.println(...);
```

**Note** that since you are using `arr[i+1]` you have to loop over the array `length - 1`, or you will get an Exception.

Comment: If this finds a double letter, this still print the "normal word found" string.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter word: ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String word = scanner.nextLine();

for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i + 1)) {
        System.out.println("word contain double letter");

    } else {
        System.out.println("normal word found");
    }
}
```

Comment: try out this word 'ihatexceptions'

Comment: It should be word.length()-1

Answer (score 0):

Easier way is to have a set of [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) keep adding to that and if length of that set is different from length of Word. u had duplicate char.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access characters in a String using string[i]

try something like

```
for (i = 1; i < word.length()-1; i++) {
        if (word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i+1)) {
            System.out.println("word contain double letter");

        } else {
            System.out.println("normal word found");
        }
    }
```